# PHP - JSON to HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am trying to display json_encode data from my back end controller to view using together with **AJAX**. The **AJAX** runs successfully and received the response that I needed. However, i am unable to display out on my **HTML**.

I have double-checked that there is certainly a response coming from the back end. Please do help me.

**AJAX jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'index.php/Status/facility',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {id:id},
        success: function (response) {

            var len = response.length;

            console.log(len);

        for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
            var id = response[i].facility_id;
            var username = response[i].name;

            var tr_str = "<li class='pointer' id='" + (i+1) + "' onclick='changeClass(this.id)'><a>" + name +"</a></li>";

            $("#tabAjax").append(tr_str);
        }

          $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show'); 

        }
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="tabAjax"></ul>
```

**Controller**

```
public function facility(){
    echo json_encode($data);
    //$this->load->view('templates/student/footer');
}
```

**Response**

```
{"facility_list":[{"facility_id":"1","name":"Table 1","facility_category":"1"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to access the data within `facility_list` so to do so firstly get a reference to that level of the response data and then iterate through it's child objects

```
var json=response.facility_list;

for( var n in json ){
    var obj=json[n];

    var id=obj.facility_id;
    var name=obj.name;
    var cat=obj.facility_category;

    var tr_str = "<li class='pointer' data-category='"+cat+"' id='" + (n+1) + "' onclick='changeClass(this.id)'><a>" + name +"</a></li>";

    $("#tabAjax").append( tr_str );
}
```

Comment: oh great it work! Totally didn't know about the facility_list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this handle it at backend. You can prepared html at backend and send prepared html in response(in any key of array) and append according that. That will be more easy to handle response and no need to reload page every time.

```
$response = array(array('facility_id' => 1, 'facility_category' => 2, 'name' => 'abc'));
$returnResponse = array('status' => 'false', 'data' => '');
$str = '';
foreach ($response as $key => $resp) {
$str .= '<li class="pointer" data-category="' . $resp['facility_category'] . '" id="' . ($key+1) . '" onclick="changeClass(this.id)"><a> ' . $resp['name'] . ' </a></li>';
}
$returnResponse['status'] = true;
$returnResponse['data'] = $str;
```

Now in js file you can use:-

```
var html = response.data;
```

and append above html where you want.